# problem in lightbox for video?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am using a thick box for flv player, when we click on the link for video  (these videos list coming via AJAX), large size of videos are not playing, i think it is buffered, how can play the large videos? i am using flv player downloaded from www.adobe.com.

Answer (score 0):

How large your large videos are ?
What server do you use (apache, ...) / what script language (php, ...) ?

Maybe your problem can be solved with a little bit of server configuration.
If you're using Apache/Php, try to increase the amount of memory php can access (in php.ini file)